# Why doesn't "git status" show that the remote branch has changed?

Tags: git

I have created a branch `fea-test` and pushed to the remote repository. Then, I added some files in the same remote branch `fea-test`, but when I do `git status`, it says

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/fea-test'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

According to me, it should display something like

```
Your branch is behind  with 'origin/fea-test'.
    
    use git pull to get the changes
```

because this is how it happens in GitLab (and now I'm using GitHub). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No.  You won't see any difference between the tracking branch unless it becomes out of sync with the remote.  And to make a commit from the CL you would need to `git add` some files and then do a `git commit`.

Comment: Please clarify the steps to let us reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, check that these the steps you did:

- Create a branch on local machine
- Push to remote (GitHub)
- On GitHub, you added a new file via *Create new file* button
- You called `git status` on local machine and expected the newly created files / commits to be listed.

If I'm right, then you have to `git fetch` the changes from GitHub (so `Your branch is behind of 'origin/fea-test' by XY commits` will be shown in status) or use `git pull` to fetch + merge those (so your local branch will be updated).

[Be sure that you know Git!](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)